# How to print "node title" in comment.html.twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, comments

i am styling my comments in comment.html.twig template and need to show "node title" of the node to which the comments belong.

I've tried a number of options, and the only one that works relatively is below:

```
function enar_preprocess_comment(&$variables){
   $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
   $variables['nodetitle'] = $node->getTitle();
}
```

However, if I click "reply" in the comments, I get this error.

```
Error: Call to a member function getTitle() on null in mytheme_preprocess_comment()
```

My question is, how to print "node title" in comment.html.twig template?

Comment: `$node = $variables['commented_entity'];`

Answer (score 1):

Because the comment reply page/route does not belong to a Node entity

```
$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
```

returns null.

Instead, access the node object with

```
$node = $variables['commented_entity'];
```